# Ignorar propriedade com FluentNHibernate?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Estou tentando ignorar uma propriedade de uma classe para mapeamento com FluentNHibernate e não estou conseguindo. Estou tentando seguir esse exemplo [link](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping#ignoring-properties). Como fazer isso ?

tentando.

```
public class Caixa {

        public virtual long id                      { set; get; }
        public virtual DateTime dtOcorrencia        { set; get; }
        public virtual String historico             { set; get; }
        public virtual int tipoOcorrencia           { set; get; } //1 entrada, 2 saida
        public virtual decimal valorOcorrencia      { set; get; }
        public virtual FormaPagamento formaPagto    { set; get; }

        //ignorar propriedade
        public IList<Caixa> report = new List<Caixa>();

        public Caixa () {
        }

        public IList<Caixa> getReport() {
            return report;
        }

    }
```

**Map**

```
public class CaixaMap : ClassMap<Caixa> {
        public CaixaMap() {
            Table("CAIXA");
            Id(c => c.id).GeneratedBy.Native();
            Map(c => c.dtOcorrencia).CustomType<DateTime>();
            Map(c => c.historico);
            Map(c => c.tipoOcorrencia).CustomType<int>();
            Map(c => c.valorOcorrencia).CustomType<decimal>().Precision(15).Scale(2);            
            Map(c => c.formaPagto).CustomType<GenericEnumMapper<FormaPagamento>>();
            Map(c => c.report); //ignorar 

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que um item não seja mapeado pelo [FluentNhibernate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentNHibernate/), oculte o item na ***classe de configuração*** (`ClassMap`), exemplo:

```
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

namespace Models
{

    public class Client
    {        
        public virtual int Id { set; get; }    
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
            }
        }

    }
    public class ClientMap : ClassMap<Client>
    {
        public ClientMap()
        {
            Table("client");

            Id(c => c.Id)
                .GeneratedBy
                .Identity()
                .Column("id")
                .Not.Nullable();

            Map(c => c.FirstName)
                .Column("firstname")
                .Length(15)
                .Not.Nullable();

            Map(c => c.LastName)
                .Column("lastname")
                .Length(50)
                .Not.Nullable();
        }        
    }

}
```

Na *classe* `Client`, tem um ***`FullName`*** que na *classe* `ClientMap` não foi configurado e o mesmo será ignorado nas operações de ***criar***, ***alterar*** e ***deletar***, sendo possivel na leitura (item único ou uma lista) ler a propriedade ***FullName***

Na classe que gerenciar deve ser configurado:

```
public class Database
{
    public ISession Session { get; private set; }
    public ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; private set; }     
    public Database()
    {
        SessionFactory = Fluently
            .Configure()
            .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("MyConnectionString")))                
            .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ClientMap>())
            .BuildSessionFactory();

        Session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

---

***Salvando registro:***

```
Database db = new Database();
Client c = new Client
{
   FirstName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 9),
   LastName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
};
var trans = db.Session.BeginTransaction();
db.Session.Save(c);            
trans.Commit();
db.Session.Flush();
```

**Referencia:**

- [NHibernate - Learning with Code Samples](http://www.fincher.org/tips/Languages/NHibernate.shtml)